# Yii2: How to send a model and an array that doesn't belong to the model

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I need to send a form from the view to the controller and also an **array that doesn't belong to the model**.

I always send my form using this sentence:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Send') ?>
```

Now I need to send also an array called **colors**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in your form all the fields you need

```
<input type='text' class='form-control'  name = 'yourname[your_index]'  >
```

then in controller you can read the content of $_POST using

```
 $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
```

in $post you obtain the values relate  to the model using

```
    $model->load($post)
```

the value not related to the model  are in

```
$post[yourname[your_index]]
```